# Fetch duplicate records in different scenarios

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query to find out duplicate where column B values are different.Basically I need to write queries for three scenarios.

Scenario 1:

My requirement is that "I need the COL A value as output only if within a group all the values in the column B should be different and out of the different values one of the value in COL B should be EXTERNAL"

I already got the query for scenario from my old post

```
SELECT test.colA
FROM test INNER JOIN (
    SELECT colA, COUNT(DISTINCT colB) AS cntUnique, COUNT(colB) AS cntAll 
    FROM test
    GROUP BY colA
)t ON test.colA = t.colA
GROUP BY test.colA
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN colB = 'EXTERNAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
    AND MAX(t.cntUnique) = MAX(t.cntAll)
```

Scenario 2:

My requirement is that "I need the COL A value as output only if within a group one of value in the column B should be EXTERNAL, but all the values within the group shouldn't be different and there should be some other values present in COLB other than the value EXTERNAL.

Scenario 3:

Need to select all the records which will not fall under scenario 1 and scenario 2

My sample record and its desired result is given below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your Scenario 1 I think this will work too:

```
SELECT colA
FROM test 
GROUP BY colA
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN colB = 'EXTERNAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
  AND 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ColB) = COUNT(*)
```

For your Scenario 2 the number of rows containing `'EXTERNAL'` should be greater than 0 and less than the total number of rows - 1 for each value of `colA`:

```
SELECT colA
FROM test 
GROUP BY colA
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN colB = 'EXTERNAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) BETWEEN 1 AND COUNT(*) - 2 
  AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN colB <> 'EXTERNAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ColB) - SUM(CASE WHEN colB = 'EXTERNAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

For your Scenario 3 the number of rows containing `'EXTERNAL'` should be either 0 or equal to the total number of rows for each value of `colA`:

```
SELECT colA
FROM test 
GROUP BY colA
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN colB = 'EXTERNAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IN (0, COUNT(*))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0dac7010252f1d13060c4ff3569cbbf6).
Results:
Scenario **1**

```
> | colA |
> | ---: |
> |  123 |
> |  131 |
```

Scenario **2**

```
> | colA |
> | ---: |
> |  434 |
> |  567 |
```

Scenario **3**

```
> | colA |
> | ---: |
> |  121 |
> |  345 |
> |  456 |
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested this query as well and its performance is super fast

Answer (score 0):

The "All-In-One" solution. The result set must be filtered by the SCENARIO_ID column to obtain the necessary data.

```
with
  test as (
    select
      *
     from (
       values (123, 'EXTERNAL'), (123, 'INTERNAL'),
              (456, 'INTERNAL'), (456, 'IBM'), (456, 'DELL'),
              (345, 'EXTERNAL'), (345, 'EXTERNAL'), (345, 'EXTERNAL'),
              (434, 'INTERNAL'), (434, 'US'), (434, 'US'), (434, 'EXTERNAL'),
              (567, 'INTERNAL'), (567, 'EXTERNAL'), (567, 'EXTERNAL'), (567, 'IBM'),
              (121, 'INTERNAL'), (121, 'INTERNAL'), (121, 'INTERNAL'),
              (131, 'EXTERNAL'), (131, 'IBM')
     ) t(cola, colb)
  ),
  t as (
    select
      cola,
      count(*) qnt,
      count(distinct colb) distinct_qnt,
      sum(iif(colb = 'EXTERNAL', 1, 0)) external_qnt
    from test
    group by cola
  )
select
  cola,
  iif(external_qnt = 0 or external_qnt = qnt,
        3, iif(external_qnt = 1 and distinct_qnt = qnt, 1, 2)) scenario_id
from t;
```

**Output:**

```
+------+-------------+
| cola | scenario_id |
+------+-------------+
|  121 |           3 |
|  123 |           1 |
|  131 |           1 |
|  345 |           3 |
|  434 |           2 |
|  456 |           3 |
|  567 |           2 |
+------+-------------+
```

Test it online with [Rextester](https://rextester.com/WYZN60166).

Comment: Sorry for asking another question, how to write this query without passing the values. I need the query by just passing the col names and table names. For ex my table name is TEST and col names are COL A and COLB

Comment: @GIN, do you need dynamic SQL? Look at this article https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/. But remember the dangers of SQL injection.